# Clicking Hastily Causes Routing Issue

Tags: ionic-framework

I have a simple Ionic v1 app that displays a list of items. Clicking on an item navigates the user to a new view displaying info about the item.

If the user selects a **second** before the first item is loaded, the app will navigate to both views respectively, which is an issue.

Is there a way to prevent this via an ionic config or angular?

Note I am using Ionic Native Transitions, but this issue seems to be independent

*Edit * I know I can use something like a 'loading' modal to prevent clicks, but then I'll have to do this for every single list in the application that loads data, so that doesn't sound ideal

Answer (score 0):

I ended up utilizing `inoicNativeTransition.beforeTransition` in order to render a modal-style backdrop that prevents users from clicking for 300ms

```
  $rootScope.$on('ionicNativeTransitions.beforeTransition', function(){
    $rootScope.stateTransitioning = true;
    $timeout(function(){
      $rootScope.stateTransitioning = false;
    }, 300)
  });
```

HTML

```
  <div ng-show="stateTransitioning === true" id="inivisible-backdrop"> </div>
```

I don't hide the backdrop on the `success` of the transition, because there seems to be an inconsistent lag between when the view is changed and the transition is marked as 'successful'. 300ms seems to work just fine